# AngularJS server and client side form validation

Tags: javascript, mvvm, validation, angularjs

I have some trouble combining client side validation and server side validation in AngularJS. Here's the HTML:

```
<form class="form-login" name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="login()">
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <input type="text" required class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" name="username">
        <div ng-show="loginForm.username.$dirty && loginForm.username.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">Username required.</span>
        </div>
        <input type="password" required class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" name="password">
        <div ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required">Password required.</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="loginForm.username.$dirty && loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.$invalid">
            <span>Invalid username or password</span>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#forgotPassword" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-link">Forgot password?</a></p>
        <p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" type="submit">Login</button></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

...and here's the login function:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $http.post('url', {
        "password": $scope.password
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (404 === status) {
            $scope.loginForm.$invalid = true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The client side validation works fine until I submit the form and get back a 404 status. When the 404 status is returned the loginForm.$invalid error shows up but the client side validation doesn't change the form state back to valid when I change the username and password inputs again.

Is there a standard way to do this kind of client side + server side validation in the same form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're supposed to modify form `$invalid` or `$valid` directly. You should be doing it via `$setValidity(validationErrorKey, isValid)`.

Why not just store "invalid username/password" status in a separate scope property?

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $http.post('url', {
        "password": $scope.password
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (404 === status) {
            $scope.invalidUsernamePassword = true; // <--------------
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And the template will be simpler:

```
<div ng-show="invalidUsernamePassword">
    <span>Invalid username or password</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You really have a point here :) Before I posted my issue here I tried to do $scope.loginForm.$setValidity('somekey', false) and the result was that it created $scope.loginForm.$error.somekey equal to undefined. I probably didn't do it right. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: @lucassp There are two `$setValidity` methods. One on the form controller and the other on the ngModel controller. And the thing is, the first one is internal method and you're not really supposed to be calling it directly (it actually takes three parameters).

So you should be doing something like this instead: `username.$setValidity('validCredentials', false)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice server side validation directive that might be usefull https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/6v-AillQboI/D0OaZzV7Me0J